# Chartboost Swift Implementation: CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'CBHTTPRequestEntity' for entity 'CBHTTPRequestEntity'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, chartboost

I'm using Swift with Xcode 6.3 and want to implement Chartboost.

I already added the Bridging Header with the required imports

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Chartboost/Chartboost.h>
#import <Chartboost/CBNewsfeed.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
#import <AdSupport/AdSupport.h>
```

Now when start with my app ID, I get the following error:

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'CBHTTPRequestEntity' for entity 'CBHTTPRequestEntity'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

Surprisingly, the Interstitial AD is displayed. 
So how do I get rid of this error/warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer for my own question here: [Chartboost Common Problems](https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201219965-Common-Problems-and-Solutions#20)

Not to worry – this is just a warning, and poses no risk to customers.

In order to keep the Chartboost SDK integration simple and straightforward for developers, we dynamically link iOS frameworks as needed by our SDK. While this benefits users, it also comes with some internal tradeoffs (like the generation of this particular warning message):

```
CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'CBHTTPRequestEntity' for entity 'CBHTTPRequestEntity'. Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
```

While we've verified that these warnings can safely be ignored, rest assured that we're also working on a long-term solution to prevent them appearing in future integrations.